# Is there a way to authorize an ssh machine?

Tags: permissions, ssh, git

Currently my host machine has a private key but I would like to develop on a remote machine via ssh, so I need to clone from a private git repository from that remote machine.

Is there a way to give temporary privileges to the machine that I am ssh'ing into so that I can clone from that machine?

Of course there are solutions like generating a private key for the remote machine, or copying over the files via ssh. Just wondering if there is a simple alternative.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is, you can forward your keys without copying them. Instead of `ssh user@server` you use `ssh -A user@server`. When you are logged to the remote machine you can check what keys you can use by `ssh-add -l`.